# Unwanted insertion in recognized text

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-speech

Is there a way to remove an insertion in result in my custom speech project in custom speech studio?

My audio is in Portuguese and my transcript too. The test result after training has inserted an unwanted word. This unwanted word will harm the quality of speech in this way.

Comment: Try some other ASR toolkit, you'll get much better accuracy ;)

Comment: Hi Nikolay, it isn't possible. I have to create a solution with Microsoft speech toolkit.